# Global variable for Jade templates in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, global-variables, pug

I am using `node.js` with `Jade` templating system.

Assume, I have these routing rules:

```
// ./routes/first.js

exports.first = function(req, res)
{
    res.render('first', {
        author: 'Edward',
        title: 'First page'
    });
};

// ./routes/second.js

exports.second = function(req, res)
{
    res.render('second', {
        author: 'Edward',
        title: 'Second page'
    });
};
```

And these dummy views:

```
// ./views/first.jade

html
    head
        title #{author} &ndash; #{title}
    body
        span First page content

// ./views/second.jade

html
    head
        title #{author} &ndash; #{title}
    body
        span Second page content
```

How can I declare `author` variable generally, for both views?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718818/express-js-view-globals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ./author.js
module.exports = 'Edward';

// ./routes/first.js

exports.first = function(req, res)
{
    res.render('first', {
        author: require('../author'),
        title: 'First page'
    });
};

// ./routes/second.js

exports.second = function(req, res)
{
    res.render('second', {
        author: require('../author'),
        title: 'Second page'
    });
};
```

or

```
// ./views/includes/head.jade
head
    title Edward &ndash; #{title}

// ./views/first.jade

html
    include includes/head
    body
        span First page content

// ./views/second.jade

html
    include includes/head
    body
        span Second page content
```

or

```
// ./views/layout.jade
html
    head
        title Edward &ndash; #{title}
    body
        block body

// ./views/first.jade

extends layout
append body
    span First page content

// ./views/second.jade

extends layout
append body
    span Second page content
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been using inherited templates, as you proposing in second variant. Just wondered, if it is possible to make it easier. Haven't found anything better yet. :) First example just complicates.

Comment: Use `app.locals.author = "Jeffry"` instead so you do not have to repeat your code everywhere (DRY - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @JanJůna , do not use global state so you can test and support your code easily (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#Use)