# get user agent from inside jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to port a script I wrote for groovy over to jade, and have run into a stumbling block

I need to access the user-agent from inside a jade file. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 - var agent = req.headers['user-agent'];
 - var agent = headers['user-agent'];
 - var agent = navigator.userAgent;
```

every time I get a 500 error from express. Is this even possible?

I know I could do it in a module and pass it to the render statement, but that would mean passing it to EVERY render, as it needs to be global.

Very new to node, and confused. Thanks SO.

Comment: It should be passed to render everytime a request comes, user-agent can be different for every request.

Comment: and jade is rendered for each request

Comment: yes, response is rendered for each request separately.

Comment: so there is no reason I should not be able to access the user-agent in the .jade file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just write your own tiny middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.ua = req.get('User-Agent');
  next();
});
```

Put this before your `app.router`

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());

  // here
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.ua = req.get('User-Agent');
    next();
  });

  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

Then you can use the `ua` variable in any `jade` template (for example `index.jade`)

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p=ua
```

Comment: Worked great. Just one quick follow up question, why is the placement under app.configure important?

Comment: good question! you could probably put it anywhere you want. I tend to put my middleware just before the router because then all the processing (parsing the body, sessions, etc.) is done and the routes are handled.

Comment: I put it at the bottom and it broke, por que?

Comment: The router already took over and and rendered the views. Therefore your custom `res.locals.ua` variable wasn't set yet. By `anywhere` I ment anywhere before the router :)

Comment: Good tip, worked for me. I used `req.getHeader('User-Agent')` and it worked for me in `express 3.4.0`

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `user-agent` from express to jade : (see [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals))

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res){
    res.render('home.jade', {
    locals: {
            useragent: req.getHeader('User-Agent')
            }
    });
    res.end();
});
```

in your jade file

```
html
  body
    h1 #{useragent}
script(type='text/javascript')
  var useragent = #{useragent};
```

Comment: Is this the only way? There is no way to do so globally?

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088557/global-variable-for-jade-templates-in-node-js jade scope is different from node, so you must pass it in render if you want to use it.