# How to handle user-agent in nodejs environment?

Tags: node.js, express, user-agent

I start to using the package "ua-parser" but the creator is too busy to mantain or commit... the npm ua-parser is outdate, and need to download directly from github. Someone know about other good package like ua-parser that is updated and can be used with expressjs? Or have a way to handle just with expressjs?

Comment: Note to self: https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.get

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Have you looked at:

- https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent

Or, write your own middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.ua = req.get('User-Agent');
  next();
});
```

Reference: [get user agent from inside jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375457/get-user-agent-from-inside-jade)

Answer (score 46):

There are two general situations, where you just need simple matching, and you don't need a module for this, you can just use regex in Node.

```
var isIpad = !!req.headers['user-agent'].match(/iPad/);
var isAndroid = !!req.headers['user-agent'].match(/Android/);

==> true, false
```

The other, if you need a nice clean output of browser type, this worked best for me.
https://www.npmjs.org/package/useragent

Answer (score 12):

My optimal solution for Express...lightweight/fast!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-useragent

```
  app.use(require('express-useragent').express())
```

Your middleware...

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.useragent = {
     browser: req.useragent.browser,
     version: req.useragent.version,
     os: req.useragent.os,
     platform: req.useragent.platform
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session.useragent, null ,4))
  next()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to decoder7283. Upvoted!

I have added one more info to your solution:

```
const app = express();
const useragent = require('express-useragent');
app.use(useragent.express());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.useragent) {
        let userAgentIs = (useragent) => {
            let r = [];
            for (let i in useragent) 
                if (useragent[i] === true)
                    r.push(i);
            return r;
        }
        req.session.useragent = {
            browser: req.useragent.browser,
            version: req.useragent.version,
            os: req.useragent.os,
            platform: req.useragent.platform,
            geoIp: req.useragent.geoIp, // needs support from nginx proxy
            source: req.useragent.source,
            is: userAgentIs(req.useragent),
        };
    }
    return next();
});
```

Output of `req.session.useragent`

```
{
  browser: 'Firefox',
  version: '92.0',
  os: 'Windows 10.0',
  platform: 'Microsoft Windows',
  geoIp: {},
  source: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0',
  is: [ 'isAuthoritative', 'isFirefox', 'isDesktop', 'isWindows' ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, to get user data, you can use

```
import express from 'express';
import useragent from 'express-useragent';

const app = express();
app.use(useragent.express());
```

And in the controller

```
const userAgentInfo = req.useragent;
```

And you can get

```
{
isMobile: boolean;
isMobileNative: boolean;
isTablet: boolean;
isiPad: boolean;
isiPod: boolean;
isiPhone: boolean;
isAndroid: boolean;
isBlackberry: boolean;
isOpera: boolean;
isIE: boolean;
isEdge: boolean;
isIECompatibilityMode: boolean;
isSafari: boolean;
isFirefox: boolean;
isWebkit: boolean;
isChrome: boolean;
isKonqueror: boolean;
isOmniWeb: boolean;
isSeaMonkey: boolean;
isFlock: boolean;
isAmaya: boolean;
isEpiphany: boolean;
isDesktop: boolean;
isWindows: boolean;
isWindowsPhone: boolean;
isLinux: boolean;
isLinux64: boolean;
isMac: boolean;
isChromeOS: boolean;
isBada: boolean;
isSamsung: boolean;
isRaspberry: boolean;
isBot: boolean;
isCurl: boolean;
isAndroidTablet: boolean;
isWinJs: boolean;
isKindleFire: boolean;
isSilk: boolean;
isCaptive: boolean;
isSmartTV: boolean;
silkAccelerated: boolean;
browser: string;
version: string;
os: string;
platform: string;
geoIp: { [key: string]: any };
source: string;
}
```