# How to get OS username in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, userid

How would I get/find the username that the computer owner is using currently (while logged in), using NodeJS?

I have searched around a bit, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I am not sure why, but someone added an answer and then deleted it quickly after... I was fast enough to catch it though, and after checking, it is the shortest and most effective way of doing what I asked before:

`require("os").userInfo().username`

The only problem is, in Windows 10, it returns the first name of the owner account that has been used (just a heads up).
Everything else works completely fine!

Comment: I did but only because it only is available in v7 of nodejs. its a new feature that electron probably cant use. if it works then good!

Comment: It's not correct, node is executed on server side, so it will give you info about your server, not about the client.

Comment: where does he mention he needs a clients log-in? node.js is server side code?

Comment: "How would I find the username that the computer owner is using currently"

Comment: Ok, I understand, didn't seen the electron tag. We are not in web context, but in an heavy client context. That's ok.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot to mention it in the actual question, but I was developing a chat client that would use the  OS' username for its username...

Answer (score 25):

This one object you will get username:

```
let os = require('os')
console.log(os.userInfo());
```

Comment: It will give you the hostname of server, not client.

Comment: Actually you should use
const os = require('os');
as os is an inmutable variable.

Answer (score 17):

`process.env.USER` Should work also at least in MAC or Linux. e.g.

```
let user = process.env.USER || ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependency free method:

```js
function getUsername() {
    return (
        process.env.SUDO_USER ||
        process.env.C9_USER ||
        process.env.LOGNAME ||
        process.env.USER ||
        process.env.LNAME ||
        process.env.USERNAME
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, the easiest way to do it is using [`username`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/username)

#### Install:

```
$ npm install username
```

#### Then:

```
const username = require('username');

(async () => {
    console.log(await username());
    //=> 'current_username'
})();
```

Comment: Hai @carlos, I have implemented the same and tried to add this code in one GET rest api. I am trying to attach the response of username() function to response.send() method but its not returning. Please find the code i am trying below:
 var user = (async () => {
  await username();
 })();

 res.status(200).send({
  success: 'true',
  message: user
 });

Comment: Please ingnore my above comment, it got resolved .
Hai @carlos,
When i tried to move the same code to linux server and using GET rest api i am hitting from client machine. I am getting the linux server user but not the client user who is hitting the url. The same worked in my windows machine as i am running the application locally.
Any help regarding this.!?

Comment: @kishoreaoe this module will basically return to you the logged in user(in this case the server user), you will need to work around that to find out how does this module can help you get the client user, probably not because it will get you the root or logged in username.

Comment: Not a good habit to just use a random 3rd party module for everything.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
app.getPath('home')
```

It'll return the home path of the current user.

Comment: I use this for electron on Ubuntu and it works fine. Unsure why the downvotes. `/home/<username>`
`const home = app.getPath('home');`

Comment: Reasons why people might downvote this include: (1) assumes electron [though the OP admittedly did include the electron tag] & (2) this does not return the user information but rather the user's home directory, which might be related but is not the same. 
Node's built-in [`os.userInfo`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#osuserinfooptions) and [`os.homedir`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#oshomedir) are likely more suitable for what the OP actually asks.

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't need to be cross operating systems (just *nix based), one way you could do (keep in mind that exec could be potentially risky to use if you parameterize it):

```
const Promise = require( 'bluebird' ),
      exec    = Promise.promisify( require( 'child_process' ).exec );

exec( 'id -un' ).then( ( username )=> {
 // do something about it
});
```

If you want to use bluebird for promises, don't forget about: `npm install bluebird --save`

Comment: Checkout the [`userid` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/userid) (which I maintain). Does this without spawning extra processes.

Answer (score -8):

If you want to get information about the client witch call a route on your server, you have to parse client useragent.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

You can get client user agent with node using those examples :

[How to handle user-agent in nodejs environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285921/how-to-handle-user-agent-in-nodejs-environment)

Comment: This is completely unrelated to what the OP is asking.