# Outputting the username in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I would really know how to output the username in Electron applications. So something like that:

```
const os = require('os')
const username = // the code or the username so that it can be displayed
document.write("The username is: " + username)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find OS username in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424298/find-os-username-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Out of the box, the username is available through:

```
const os = require ('os');
const username = os.userInfo ().username;
```

Also (at least on Mac OS X and Linux) it can be obtained through the LOGNAME or USER environment variables:

```
username = process.env["LOGNAME"];
// or
username = process.env["USER"];
```

Comment: In windows this will return the first name of the user not the username.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [username](https://www.npmjs.com/package/username) node module ---

```
const username = require('username');

username().then(username => {
    console.log(username);
    //=> 'sindresorhus' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`sync()` method returns the same but without promises

```
document.write(username.sync());
```