How to get someone's Computer Username in JavaScript. Like the "whoami" Command in CMD
I'm trying to make a meta game and for one of the planned scenes I want the player's name inside a book. The thing is... I'm using PenguinMod, a block programming language that has almost nothing to do with JavaScript. Except for an Extension that you can install with blocks that run diffrent JavaScript commands depending on what you put in them. Example Image.The Javascript Blocks in Question
So I tried looking up tutorials and found nothing. I even tried looking on here [Stack Overflow] and found nothing. I was expecting to find a command you could input that'll grab the Name you use on your computer but it just doesn't seem like that exists. The only thing I could get from what I lookuped was how to get a Users IP Adress. So now my only hope is that you can help out in some way. Thank you.

If your code runs in a web browser, the answer is you cannot get that information.

web pages inside browsers have VERY limited access to such information for obvious reasons

with blocks that run diffrent JavaScript commands that's not how you write an extension

Depends on the environment your code is runnig in. In the browser you can't get that data because of security and privacy reasons. Nodejs or electron have interfaces to the OS. For instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424298/how-to-get-os-username-in-nodejs

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I've concluded that It's impossible. :(
