# Node Js - Identify if the request is coming from mobile or non-mobile device

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I'm still new with node js. Is there any workaround or methods on how to identify the request from client-side is from mobile or non-mobile devices using node js? Because what i'm doing now is i want to restrict the access on certain API based on the device type (mobile / desktop). I'm using restify for the server-side. Thanks.

Comment: You could use an `npm` package to grab detailed information for each device that visits your website - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bowser

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286027/8159775, it should help!

Answer (score 9):

The method I'd suggest is to use the npm package [`express-useragent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-useragent) since is more reliable over the long term.

```js
var http = require('http')
  , useragent = require('express-useragent');
 
var srv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var source = req.headers['user-agent']
  var ua = useragent.parse(source);
  
  // a Boolean that tells you if the request 
  // is from a mobile device
  var isMobile = ua.isMobile

  // do something more
});
 
srv.listen(3000);
```

It also works with expressJS:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var useragent = require('express-useragent');
 
app.use(useragent.express());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.useragent.isMobile);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: If using Typescript, make sure to import `@types/express-useragent` in your package so that `Request` type is correctly extended

Comment: It seems that `ua-parser-js` is the standard library for parsing user-agent strings now. `express-useragent` hasn't been updated in 3 years at this point. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js

Answer (score 7):

@H.Mustafa, a basic way to detect if a client is using a mobile device is by matching a particular set of strings in the `userAgent`.

```
function detectMob() {
    const toMatch = [
        /Android/i,
        /webOS/i,
        /iPhone/i,
        /iPad/i,
        /iPod/i,
        /BlackBerry/i,
        /Windows Phone/i
    ];

    return toMatch.some((toMatchItem) => {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(toMatchItem);
    });
}
```

*(Reference: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser))*

Run this snippet of code in client's device. If the returned result is `true`, you know it's a mobile device else a desktop/laptop. Hope this helps.