# How to access a JavaScript variable value in pug?

Tags: javascript, pug

My **index.pug** file looks like this:

```
head
    script(type="text/javascript").
        var isMobile = (screen.width || window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) <= 480;
body
    if isMobile
        include nav_mobile
    else
        include nav
```

I wrote the above code but don't get the desired result. (`isMobile` seems to be always `null`)

How can I get the value of the JavaScript variable to pug?

Comment: If the `ìnclude` is on the server, then the test will be false on the server since there is no screen, window, document etc

Comment: @mplungjan sorry, It's my typo. it is var in my original code :)

Comment: @mplungjan thx to answer :) Is there another way to detect the screen size and include other views?

Comment: I do not know pug, perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375457/get-user-agent-from-inside-jade

Comment: How do you render this pug view?

Comment: @mplungjan sincerely thanks, I'll try it XD

Comment: @YvesKipondo It seems like Express. I have inherited this code from a senior, and I am still studying. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to get the screen size. Specifically, to pug, I would suggest writing a page with a script that gets the screen size and [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) to the right endpoint or adds the details to the session or maybe to the URL query and then sends them to the server, and then you can get them on your route and pass them to the [pug renderer](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugcompilesource-options).

Also in the future, I would suggest using CSS to handle mobile/desktop design and not using javascript to act upon it. Because if you change the screen size while you are on either version it won't change the design you'll have to reload the page.

Answer (score -1):

In your request handler which render that view you must pass the list of variables which you want to be accessible within your view

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // your code goes here
   // you pass each variable in the second parameter to the render method of response object
    res.render('index', { isMobile: true });
});
```

Comment: How would executing client side JS work in your example?

Comment: Before you express app render the view. The pug engine which is register in you express app as a template engine will process your **index.pug** file an return to your browser HTML relatided to your template file. In the html generate you will not have all the if statement of pug

Comment: That is not what I meant. OP wants to detect the browser, the app.get is on the server so unless a previous page has detected the browser and possibly set a cookie, you will not be able to determine which object to render