# Pass Node env to layout.jade in Express without explicitly defining route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

So, I get passing parameters to Jade files- piece of pie:

```
app.use('/myroute', function (req, res) {
  res.render('myview', {somevar: 'Testing!'});
});
```

**However**- I have my layout.jade file that is implicitly read and rendered by Express, with no actual definition of route-view binding, and I'm trying to work out how to pass a variable into that template.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Ps- this is so that I can pass node's development/production variable to some front-end javascript that's being added on every page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, I worked out the answer. Set it as a local variable in express, as mentioned here: [Express.js View "globals"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718818/express-js-view-globals)

So, in app.js I included `app.locals.env = app.settings.env;` and then in my layout.jade I added my javascript and simply used `#{env}` inside the script to get the environment value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if I pre-compile jade templates using `jade.compileFile` . Any idea how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `#{settings.env}` in the jade template, which get the value from `app.locals.settings.env`